# Uncaught TypeError: dc.leafletMarkerChart is not a function

Tags: d3.js, leaflet, dc.js, crossfilter

I am trying to add marker cluster on my dc.js charts and get stuck with this error.individual code is running but on merging it with the pie chart ,bar chart and the map , the marker are not displaying.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/dc.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/leaflet.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/leaflet.css" />

      <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js'></script>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/d3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/crossfilter.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/dc.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/underscore.js"></script>
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> -->



</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 dc-data-count dc-chart" id="data-count">
      <h2>Ground Water Analysis
        <small>
          <span class="filter-count"></span> selected out of <span class="total-count"></span> records |
           <a id="all" href="#">Reset All</a>
          </span>
        </small>
      </h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="control-row">
    <div class="col-xs-2 pie-chart">
      <h4>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;YEAR <small><a id="year">reset</a></small></h4>
      <div class="dc-chart" id="chart-ring-year"></div>
    </div>


     <div class="col-xs-2 pie-chart">
      <h4>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;DISTRICT<small><a id="month" href="#">reset</a></small></h4>
      <div class="dc-chart" id="chart-ring-month"></div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-xs-16">
      <h4><center>Map</center></h4>
      <div id="map"></div>
    </div>

    </div>

  </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
    <div class="divide">
      <div class="dc-chart" id="chart-rating-count"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
    <div class="divide1">
      <div class="dc-chart" id="chart-community-rating-count"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
    <div class="divide2">
      <div class="dc-chart" id="chart-abv-count"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
    <div class="divide3">
      <div class="dc-chart" id="chart-ibu-count"></div>
    </div>
    </div>


<script>
var map = L.map( 'map', {
    center: [20.5937,78.9629],
    minZoom: 2,
    zoom: 3,

});


var Markers = new L.FeatureGroup();

L.tileLayer( 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
    subdomains: ['a','b','c']
}).addTo( map );

    d3.json("file/edited.json", function(error, data) {



        var welldata = data.items;
        drawMarkerSelect(welldata);



        function drawMarkerSelect(welldata) { 
          var xf = crossfilter(welldata);
          var groupname = "marker-select";
          var facilities = xf.dimension(function(d) { return d.LAT; });
          var facilitiesGroup = facilities.group().reduceCount();

          var marker = dc.leafletMarkerChart("#demo1.map",groupname)
              .dimension(facilities)
              .group(facilitiesGroup)
              .width(600)
              .height(400)            
              .fitOnRender(true)
              .fitOnRedraw(true)
              .popupOnHover(true)
              .cluster(true);

          var types = xf.dimension(function(d) { return d.DISTRICT; });
          var typesGroup = types.group().reduceCount();


      dc.renderAll(groupname);

          return {marker: marker};   }

        welldata.forEach(function(d) {


        d.YEAR_OBS = d.YEAR_OBS.match(/\d+/)[0];
        d.DISTRICT = d.DISTRICT.match(/\w+/);



            //d.count = +d.count;
            //round to nearest 0.25
            d.MONSOON = +d.MONSOON;
            d.PREMONSOON = +d.PREMONSOON;
            d.POSTMONSOO=+d.POSTMONSOO;
            d.POSTMONS_1=+d.POSTMONS_1;
            //d.DISTRICT=+d.DISTRICT;
            //d.beer.rating_score = Math.round(+d.beer.rating_score * 4) / 4;
            //round to nearest 0.5
            //d.beer.beer_abv = Math.round(+d.beer.beer_abv * 2) / 2;
            //round to nearest 10
            //d.beer.beer_ibu = Math.floor(+d.beer.beer_ibu / 10) * 10;
            //d.first_had_dt = fullDateFormat.parse(d.first_had);
            //d.first_had_year = +yearFormat(d.first_had_dt);

        });

        //set crossfilter
        var ndx = crossfilter(welldata);

        //create dimensions (x-axis values)
          var yearDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.YEAR_OBS;}),
          dist = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.DISTRICT;}),
        //dc.pluck:  short hand for same kind of anonymous function we used for yearDim

                    ratingDim = ndx.dimension(dc.pluck('MONSOON')),
                    ratingDim1 = ndx.dimension(dc.pluck('PREMONSOON')),
                    ratingDim2 = ndx.dimension(dc.pluck('POSTMONSOO')),
                    ratingDim3 = ndx.dimension(dc.pluck('POSTMONS_1')),
                //commRatingDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.beer.rating_score;}),
                //abvDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.PREMONSOON;}),
                //ibuDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.beer.beer_ibu;}),
                allDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d;});

        //creating groups (y-axis values)
        var all = ndx.groupAll();
        var countPerYear = yearDim.group().reduceCount(),
        countPerDist = dist.group().reduceCount(),

                countPerRating = ratingDim.group().reduceCount()
                countPerRating1 = ratingDim1.group().reduceCount()
                countPerRating2 = ratingDim2.group().reduceCount()
                countPerRating3= ratingDim3.group().reduceCount();


                //countPerCommRating = commRatingDim.group().reduceCount();
                //countPerABV = abvDim.group().reduceCount();
                //countPerIBU = ibuDim.group().reduceCount();

        //creating charts
         var yearChart = dc.pieChart('#chart-ring-year'),
         monthChart   = dc.pieChart('#chart-ring-month'),

                ratingCountChart = dc.barChart('#chart-rating-count'),
                ratingCountChart1 = dc.barChart('#chart-community-rating-count'),
                ratingCountChart2 = dc.barChart('#chart-abv-count'),
                ratingCountChart3 = dc.barChart('#chart-ibu-count'),
                //commRatingCountChart = dc.barChart('#chart-community-rating-count'),
                //abvCountChart = dc.barChart('#chart-abv-count'),
                //ibuCountChart = dc.barChart('#chart-ibu-count'),
                dataCount = dc.dataCount('#data-count'),
                dataTable = dc.dataTable('#data-table');

        ////chart configuration

        //circle charts
        yearChart
            .width(200)
            .height(200)
            .dimension(yearDim)
            .group(countPerYear)
            .innerRadius(20);

        monthChart
            .width(200)
            .height(200)
            .dimension(dist)
            .group(countPerDist)
            .innerRadius(20);




        //bar charts
        ratingCountChart
            .width(350)
            .height(230)
            .dimension(ratingDim)
            .group(countPerRating)
            .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([-0.2, d3.max(welldata, function (d) { return d.MONSOON; }) + 0.2]))

            .y(d3.scale.linear().domain([-0.2, d3.max(welldata, function (d) { return d.MONSOON>0; }) + 0.2]))
            .elasticY(true)
            .centerBar(true)
            .barPadding(5)
            .xAxisLabel('MONSOON')
            .yAxisLabel('Count')

            /*.y(function(d) { return y(d.y); })
    .defined(function(d) { return d.y; }) // Omit empty values.
    .x(function(d,i) { return x(i); });
    */
            .margins({top:10, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 40});
           ratingCountChart.xAxis().tickValues([0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110]);



        ratingCountChart1
            .width(350)
            .height(230)
            .dimension(ratingDim1)
            .group(countPerRating1)
            .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([-0.2, d3.max(welldata, function (d) { return d.PREMONSOON; }) + 0.2]))
            .elasticY(true)
            .centerBar(true)
            .barPadding(5)
            .xAxisLabel('PREMONSOON')
            .yAxisLabel('Count')
            .margins({top: 2, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 50});
        ratingCountChart1.xAxis().tickValues([0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110]);



        ratingCountChart2
            .width(350)
            .height(230)
            .dimension(ratingDim2)
            .group(countPerRating2)
            .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([-0.2, d3.max(welldata, function (d) { return d.POSTMONSOO; }) + 0.2]))
            .elasticY(true)
            .centerBar(true)
            .barPadding(5)
            .xAxisLabel('POSTMONSOON')
            .yAxisLabel('Count')
            .margins({top: 10, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 50});
        ratingCountChart1.xAxis().tickValues([0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120]);

        ratingCountChart3
            .width(350)
            .height(230)
            .dimension(ratingDim3)
            .group(countPerRating3)
            .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([-0.2, d3.max(welldata, function (d) { return d.POSTMONS_1; }) + 0.2]))
            .elasticY(true)
            .centerBar(true)
            .barPadding(5)
            .xAxisLabel('POSTMONSOON_1')
            .yAxisLabel('Count')
            .margins({top: 10, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 50});
        ratingCountChart1.xAxis().tickValues([0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120]);


        dataCount
            .dimension(ndx)
            .group(all);



        //data table
        dataTable
            .dimension(allDim)
            .group(function (d) { return 'dc.js insists on putting a row here so I remove it using js'; })
            .size(100)
            .columns([
                function (d) { return d.OBJECTID; },
                function (d) { return d.YEAR_OBS; },
                function (d) { return d.MONSOON; },
                function (d) { return d.PREMONSOON; },
                function (d) { return d.POSTMONSOO; },
                function (d) { return d.POSTMONS_1; },
                function (d) { return d.DISTRICT; },


            ])
            .sortBy(function (d) { return d.OBJECTID; })
            .order(d3.ascending)
            .on('renderlet', function (table) {
                //each time table is rendered remove extra row dc.js insists on adding
                table.select('tr.dc-table-group').remove();

                 // update map with breweries to match filtered data
      /*Markers.clearLayers();
      _.each(allDim.top(Infinity), function (d) {
       // var loc;

        //var loc = d.LONG;
        var name = d.DISTRICT;
        var marker = L.marker([d.LAT]);
        marker.bindPopup("<p>"+ d.DISTRICT + " " + "</p>");
      Markers.addLayer(marker);
      });
      map.addLayer(Markers);
      map.fitBounds(Markers.getBounds());
      */


        });





        d3.selectAll('a#all').on('click', function() {
            dc.filterAll();
            dc.renderAll();
        });

        d3.selectAll('a#year').on('click', function() {
            yearChart.filterAll();
            dc.redrawAll();
        });
        d3.selectAll('a#month').on('click', function () {
    monthChart.filterAll();
    dc.redrawAll();
  });
        dc.renderAll();

        /*beerData.filter(function(d) {
var elem = document.getElementById("chart-rating-count");

        //console.log(d)
    return d.MONSOON == 0; 
})
elem.remove();
*/

    });




</script>


</body>
</html>
```

and the error is :

```
 Uncaught TypeError: dc.leafletMarkerChart is not a function
    at drawMarkerSelect (bubble.html:118)
    at bubble.html:108
    at Object.<anonymous> (d3.js:1996)
    at Object.event (d3.js:504)
    at XMLHttpRequest.respond (d3.js:1949)
﻿

​
```

Comment: `dc.leafletMarkerChart` is an extension to dc.js that's part of the [dc-addons](https://github.com/Intellipharm/dc-addons#leafletjs) library, but I don't see that script included. (Another option, largely equivalent, is [dc.leaflet.js](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.leaflet.js)).

Comment: error solved i m taking code of leaflet into charts therefore getting this error

Answer (score 0):

Note that the following page is useful to fix this issue. Make sure you install using bower and then include the scripts in the html.

https://github.com/Intellipharm/dc-addons